# Stop InfoWindow on Google Maps showing on load

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hi I am trying to integrate gmap with my website.But by default the infowindow is opened.I want to open the infowindow after clicking on the markers.How to close the infowindow on page load?

```
function initialize() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(22.4642600, 70.0690540), 6);
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        map.addMapType(G_SATELLITE_3D_MAP);
        for (var i = 0; i < newpoints.length; i++) {
            var point = new GPoint(newpoints[i][1], newpoints[i][0]);
            var popuphtml = newpoints[i][4];
            var post_url = newpoints[i][5];
            var addr = newpoints[i][6];
            var marker = createMarker(point, newpoints[i][2], popuphtml, post_url, addr);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
        }
    }
}

function createMarker(point, icon, popuphtml, post_url, addr) {
    var popuphtml = '<div id="popup">' + popuphtml + '<div><a href=' + post_url + '>Link</a></div></div>';
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(popuphtml);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(popuphtml);
    });
    return marker;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line

```
marker.openInfoWindowHtml(popuphtml);
```

so it becomes

```
function createMarker(point, icon, popuphtml, post_url, addr) {
    var popuphtml = '<div id="popup">' + popuphtml + '<div><a href=' + post_url + '>Link</a></div></div>';
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(popuphtml);
    });
    return marker;
}
```

you were calling the `openInfoWindowHtml` method immediately ... now its only called when the `click` event of the marker occurs

### Note

You are using Google Maps V2 ... this is the message from google related to V2

> Note: The Google Maps Javascript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. The V2 API will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps Javascript API.

Comment: @SubhashreePanda it should still show a marker - what JavaScript errors are you getting ?

Comment: Yes It is showing all markers but map should display locations of markers automatically.But in this case I need to search for the locations to see the markers

Comment: @SubhashreePanda then perhaps i miss read your question .... there are 2 things on a google map = a marker (which is a little red icon by default) and an info window - the info window is a little popup with some information on it. You said in your question you wanted to hide the infowindow thats shown on load .... can you add a picture to your question with the problem ?

Comment: @SubhashreePanda edit your question and add a picture - or host it somewhere - flickr ?!

Comment: I want to display info window after clicking on the markers not by default.And the map should display any marker location automatically no need to search for it.But if I am removing the line marker.openInfoWindowHtml(popuphtml); it is not working

Answer (score 0):

remove the `marker.openInfoWindowHtml(popuphtml);` after `var marker = new GMarker(point);`

Comment: Just keep the one intside the addListener-block ;)

Comment: If I am removing marker.openInfoWindowHtml(popuphtml);the map is working.But it is not showing the exact locations of marker.It should display the marker automatically no need to search the position of the marker